# What is the function of OrderedQ in these expressions?

Tags: pattern-matching, rule

Could someone please let me why the output of the two expressions change with OrderedQ in place. The first expression is as follows:

```
-o[a - b]/. o[n_? Negative x_ + y_] :> -o[- n x - y]
```

The output of the above expression is: o[-a + b]

The second expression being:

```
 -o[a - b]/. o[n_? Negative x_ + y_] :> -o[- n x - y]/;OrderedQ[{x,y}]
```

The output of the second expression is: -o[a - b]

The second expression yields the correct output (Computer Science with Mathematica, Roman Maeder). What is confusing me is why OrderedQ corrects for the discrepancy.

Answer (score 5):

This is a case where deconstructing the right hand side of the replacement rule is very helpful. Let us look at the first example,

```
-o[a - b]/. o[n_? Negative x_ + y_] :> -o[- n x - y]
```

and change a few things

```
o[a - b]/. o[n_? Negative x_ + y_] :> {n, x, y}
```

which returns

```
{-1, b, a}
```

Note, I dropped the $-1$ in front since it would just negate everything in the list. Doing something similar with the second pattern

```
o[a - b] /. o[n_?Negative x_ + y_] :> {n, x, y, OrderedQ[{x, y}]}
```

we get

```
{-1, b, a, False}
```

This tells us that `OrderedQ` is passed `{b, a}`, which is not in sorted order, so it returns `False`. In your second pattern, this has the effect that the minus sign needs to be on `a`, not `b`, for the pattern to activate, e.g.

```
-o[-a + b] /. o[n_?Negative x_ + y_] :> -o[-n x - y] /; OrderedQ[{x, y}]
(*o[a - b]*)
```

Comment: [This looks like a graphics bug.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/121922/12)  I tried to reduce the example a but. Just wanted to point it out in case you don't know about it yet.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'll poke at it.