# Why Doesn't PointLegend Work With Rotated Graphics

Tags: graphics, bugs, legending

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.0**

---

I'd like to create a PointLegend with various shapes, a diamond (rotated square) being one of them.

I'm not sure why this doesn't work with the following code:

```
PointLegend[
 ColorData[97, "ColorList"], {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"}, 
 LegendMarkerSize -> Large, 
 LegendMarkers -> 
  Graphics /@ {Rectangle[], Disk[], Rotate[Rectangle[], Pi/4], 
    Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-1, 0}}]}]
```

[image: Code Output]

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's annoying that it behaves this way, but this is a workaround:  `GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[], RotationTransform[Pi/4]]` instead of `Rotate[Rectangle[], Pi/4]`

Comment: Or alternatively: `Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use symbols:

```
PointLegend[
 ColorData[97, "ColorList"], {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"},
 LegendMarkerSize -> {25},
 LegendMarkers -> {{"\[FilledSmallSquare]", 20}, 
                   {"\[FilledSmallCircle]", 20}, 
                   {"\[FilledDiamond]", 20}, 
                   {"\[FilledUpTriangle]", 20}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer.  It is a long comment that doesn't fit in a comment.

We can see what sorts of graphics are generated by using `ToBoxes`, then extracting the `GraphicsBox` and finally using `ToExpression` to convert it back to `Graphics`.  After removing several irrelevant things from those graphics and simplifying a bit, we end up with

```
Graphics[{Inset[Graphics[GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[{0, 0}], 
            {{{0.7071067811865475, -0.7071067811865475}, {0.7071067811865475, 
                  0.7071067811865475}}, Center}], 
    DefaultBaseStyle -> 
            { Directive[EdgeForm[Red],
              RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798]]}], 
   Scaled[{1/2, 1/2}], Automatic, Scaled[1]]}]
```

This renders as empty.  Removing the `GeometricTransformation` part allows it to render properly.  Removing the `EdgeForm` directive also fixes it.  Removing the last argument of `Inset` (`Automatic`) also fixes it.

This looks like a bug.